# Gstreamer : transcoding Matroska video to mp4

Tags: gstreamer

The hardware on which we are working on doesnt support playing of mkv files.
So i'm required to transcode Matroska (mkv) video filea to mp4 video file.

As I have understood from the material available online on transcoding,I'm required to do the following :

1. separate out different streams of mkv file using **matroskademux** element.
2. decode the audio and Video streams into raw format using available mkv decoder and
    supply this data to the mp4 Muxer element and re-encode to required format.

Could anyone please tell me if I applying right approach?
Any information/link on this would be very helpful.

vikram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what is in the Matroska file you might not need to decode it at all, just remux.

I assume the video for instance is H264, so just remux that.
Below is an example pipeline for gst-launch for remuxing a file with h264 and mp3.

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=$file \
! matroskademux name="demux" demux. ! h264parse ! queue \
! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=$file._out.mp4 demux. \
! mp3parse ! queue ! mux.`
```

You can also look at the [Transmageddon transcoder](http://www.linuxrising.org) (www.linuxrising.org) which should give you want you want.

Comment: Thank You for the reply.
I have one more query:
With the above command which you mentioned i was able to remux mkv to mp4 in cases where the audio stream is mp3.
If mkv has aac audio stream then I try to use aacparser.somehow the pipeline queue is not getting linked with the aacparse element.
In one of the posts related to aacparse it is mentioned that if the "framed" field in audio stream is set to true,then "aacparse" element fails 
to link to the pipeline queue.
In this case do i need to decode the audio stream to raw format,and then re-encode it to match mp4mux element sink?

Comment: There has been a lot of fixes to parsers in GStreamer git, the goal is to have new releases out in a few weeks and those should fix your issues I think.