# Timing is lost when converting h264 video to non segmented mp4 using gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, h.264

I would like to create a non segmented .mp4 video from a matroska source. I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412688/gstreamer-transcoding-matroska-video-to-mp4) and created a similar pipeline. My source contains only h264 video and no sound, so my pipeline looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=x.mkv ! matroskademux ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=x.mp4
```

However running `gst-discoverer-1.0` on the result gives a duration of 0:00:00.000000000. Also `vlc` is not able to play the resulting .mp4 file and it cannot be used in a HTML5 `<video>` element (which is the final purpose of this conversion).

If I create a segmented .mp4 by adding `fragment-duration=1000` to the `mp4mux` element, then `vlc` can play the .mp4, but this is not what I want. **I need a .mp4 where the total length is known.** What am I doing wrong?

Additional information: The length was present in the matroska source, as displayed by `gst-discoverer-1.0`, and `vlc` can display that source. I also can replay the non segmented .mp4 with gstreamer (using `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=x.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`). Inspecting the generated `.dot` file reveals a framerate of 10000/1 coming out of `qtdemux` which seems quite strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add `disable-passthrough=true` to the `h264parse` element, so the pipeline now looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=x.mkv ! \
matroskademux ! \
h264parse disable-passthrough=true ! \
mp4mux ! \
filesink location=x.mp4
```

Now the resulting .mp4 file includes the timing information and can nicely be played with vlc as well as in a `<video>` tag including forward/backward navigation.